# Undo an operation in the neo4j schema

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-shell

After hitting `call db.schema()` in a neo4j command shell in my browser, I got the graph representation of the schema.

After hitting on one of the nodes, generally, there are set of buttons(as shown in the picture below), By mistake I hit the cross button.

[image]

Doe this modify the data in the database? If yes How do I undo this? 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the graphical view is only for display purposes currently, all you did was remove the node from the visualization. Your data hasn't been modified.

Comment: In the "on stage" movie graph example I see the same thing you said but I have done it for the production/deployment link..... I am afraid because there might be some exceptions to the "on stage" and "production". That's why I am asking still is it just the display and not actual modification to the data even in the production?

Comment: The Neo4j browser view doesn't currently have the capability of modifying the graph through the visualizer. No possibility that you could induce a change this way.